# selenium webdriver script for xml files updation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am looking to use a selenium web driver script for XML modifying files. I have to update 200 XML files for regression testing in each sprint. I need selenium Web driver scripts to automate the XML file modifications.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As known WebDriver interacts with only web browsers. Here you can update the XML files easily by language which you are using. If you are using java, then [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) will helps you.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: How to use above mentioned DOM XML parser ?